# Can I use VMWare Server internally in my small company?

Tags: licensing, vmware-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Can I use VMWare Server internally in my small company for free? From the license it is not very clear.

Comment: Since it's about some server software it might be better to ask at ServerFault, but since it's about the license rather than technical details I'm not sure. I'd suggest trying to contact VMWare to ask them.

Comment: Keep in mind that Vmware Server is pretty much a dead-end.  Their ESXi is works better and is the way forward.

Answer (score 7):

If you're referring to VMware Server as detailed here:

http://www.vmware.com/products/server

then the answer is yes. You might also try ESXi:

http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/

Comment: You really **should** switch to ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have for free ESX4i or VMware Server v2.x (but need a host OS like Windows or Linux).

ESX4i can be ran diskless (I boot my servers from a USB key) and they connect to iSCSI target on a NAS/SAN.

HTH

Luis

Comment: ESXi 3.5 can also be run from USB..

Answer (score 0):

VMware Server is totally free, and it runs on Linux or Windows. But is being discontinued by VMware (End Of Support in 2011), and there are currently no known plans for future releases.

You can use the other VMware free product, ESXi, which also performs a lot better than VMware server, being it a bare-metal hypervisor just like the full-featured ESX.